# Git - Branching from master using old commit

Tags: git, branch

Lets say that my commit graph looks like that:

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
               |
             master
```

Now, I would like to branch from HEAD using commit #2, i.e. I would like to have something like that

```
              branch
                 |
                 5
                /
1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 4
               |
             master
```

but I want commit #5 to reflect the status of the files in commit #2.

Is this possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether you want your new commit to contain the same changes as #2 did (if possible; there might be merge conflicts that prevent this):

```
git checkout -b branch
git cherry-pick hashOfSecondCommit
```

or whether you want *all* the files to look exactly the way they did at the time of #2:

```
git checkout -b branch hashOfSecondCommit
git reset --soft master
git commit
```

What `cherry-pick` does is to "replay" another commit, and `reset --soft` changes what the "active" commit is without changing the files in the working directory (as opposed to `checkout`).

Comment: Thank you ! git reset --soft is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Besides @AasmundEldhuset 's git cherry-pick, you could also use git rebase.

`git rebase --onto 2 4 5`

It looks like to remove 3 and 4 in the new branch.